# C++ access array element using a COORD struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, coordinates, coords

I was wondering if there is an easy way to access an element of a two dimensional array using a COORD struct.
for example:

```
COORD myCoord = {2,6};
TwoDiArray myArray;
myArray.at(myCoord) = 10;
```

I have no idea how to properly do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define a proper function `at()`:

```
class TwoDiArray {
   ...
   // assuming there is some 2-dimensional array representation arr
   public: 
      int& at(COORD c) noexcept { return arr[c.x][c.y]; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m making the assumption that your `TwoDArray` type is a type you can’t change and which is accessed - well - like a two dimensional array, e.g., an alias for a two dimensional built-in array (otherwise see @Jodocus’s answer). You could implement an accessory taking an array reference and a `COORD` object:

```
template <typename Array2D>
auto at(Array2D&& array, COORD c) -> decltype(array[c.x][c.y]) {
    return array[c.x][c.y];
}
```

(I don’t know the name of the `COORD` members)
You’d use the function like this:

```
at(myArray, myCoord) = 10;
```